# Yii 2. Different actions depending on passed arguments

Tags: php, url, yii, routes, yii2

**What do I want**

I want call different actions on such URLs

```
abc.com/ — Home page

abc.com/<argument-1>/<argument-2> — Search page
```

**What do I have**

Here is my `web.php` route config and Search with Index actions.

```
'urlManager' => [
            'enablePrettyUrl'     => true,
            'showScriptName'      => false,
            'enableStrictParsing' => false,
            'rules'               => [
                //Home page
                '/' => 'site/index',
                //Search
                '<tag>/<location>' => 'site/search',
            ],
        ],
```

And at `abc.com/` I get an infinite loop.

*Index action*

```
   /**
     * Displays homepage.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function actionIndex()
    {
        return $this->render('index', ['ip-info' => Locator::getLocation()]);
    }
```

*Search action*

```
public function actionSearch(
    array $tag = ['any'],
    array $location = ['any'],
    $display = 'list',
    $sort = 'name'
) {

    //...
    //some actions to fill the variables.
    //...

    return $this->render('search', [
        'data'         => $data,
        'display-type' => $display,
        'sidebar'      => $sidebar,
        'countries'    => $location,
        'sort'         => $sort,
        'title'        => $title,
    ]);
}
```

Comment: Can you post your search action

Comment: what code written in index action? please check that too

Comment: what happens if you remove / from abc.com/  try just abc.com and check view too i.e. index is there any redirection code?

Comment: @Kool-Mind **/** removing gives nothing. Looping just regular markup in view.

Comment: echo 'debug'; exit; before rendering i.e. return $this->render('index', ['ip-info' => Locator::getLocation()]); if it stops redirecting that means something mess in view.

Comment: @Kool-Mind I have an XDebug extension. As far I can see, Yii2 perfoms first action (index) and than second (search).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was in a combination of circumstances. AJAX was generating wrong route request and the nearest `catch` provide a loop. Here is the example of working rules.

```
'urlManager' => [
            'baseUrl' => '/',

            'enablePrettyUrl'     => true,
            'showScriptName'      => false,
            'enableStrictParsing' => true,
            'rules' => [
                //Home page
                '/'                 => 'site/index',

                //AJAX
                'ajax/<action:\w+>' => 'ajax/<action>',


                //Search
                '<tag:\w+>/<location:\w+>'  => 'site/search',

            ],

        ],
```